# How is Pagination done in iPhone or Xcode?

Tags: iphone, pagination, swipe

I would like to know how PAGINATION is done using a "SWIPE".

Got a page with the name "Account Details" and this "Account Details" page should have around 4 PAGEs within that Account Details of 4 more accounts.

These has got the information about the BANKING account details. So how is the PAGINATION done. for these 4 PAGEs keeping "Account Details" as the main page.

Please help me....!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand what you want, you should use `UIScrollView`!
Add this to your `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4 * self.view.bounds.width, 1); // 1 = hack to disable possible verticalBouncing
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
/* add your pages as subviews here */
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`UIPageControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Very straightforward.